# Docker compose won't use .env variables [NodeJS, Docker]

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, environment-variables

I want to use my env variable inside the docker compose file. When I try to run it I get this error for every variable in there like they weren't defined:

```
The password variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

Some context:

[image]

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8
    restart: always
    env_file: config.env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=$database
    ports:
      - $db_port:$db_docker_port
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
  app:
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    build: ./
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: config.env
    ports:
      - $port:$port_docker
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=mysqldb
      - DB_USER=$user
      - DB_PASSWORD=$password
      - DB_NAME=$database
      - DB_PORT=$db_docker_port
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
volumes: 
  db:
```

config.env:

```
database=dbname
host=localhost
user=user
password=password
port=5005
port_docker=5004
db_port=3306
db_docker_port=3307
```

Did I import the config.env file incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your environment variable file should be called `.env` and you use the variables using the syntax `${password}`.

The way you've done it - with the `env_file` statement - is used when you want the variables set *inside* the container. You can't use them in the docker-compose file, when you do it that way.

You can remove the env_file statements in the docker-compose file unless you need the variables in there as well. But it looks like you pass them all in using the docker-compose file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax

```
env_file:
 - config.env
```

Comment: thx for the suggestion but it still gives the error